# TimeoutException on Selenium test case using Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium test case that works when `headless` option is `False`, but fails when headless option is `True`.

**Environment:**

1. Mac Apple M1 Monterey Version 12.2.1
2. ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61
   (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819})
3. Chrome Browser Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (arm64)

```
import os
import time
from os import path
from os.path import expanduser
from os.path import exists
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

class MSetUp:
    
    def __init__ (self, driverName = 'chromedriver', headless=True):
        if driverName == 'chromedriver':
            path = expanduser("~/")
            if headless:
                chrome_options = Options()
                chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
                chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
            else:
                chrome_options = Options()
                chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(path + 'chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    
    def setupPPMOP(
            self, 
            redirectUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8E9818988A127210Y", 
            payPalUserEmail = "mypaypal123@gmail.com",
            payPalUserPassword = "rteMyPaypal123", 
            payPalUserCountry = 'us'):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        """ Go to paypal url """
        self.driver.get(redirectUrl)

        """ look for consent button to accept cookie """
        time.sleep(5)
        cookieAcceptConcentButton = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "acceptAllButton")))
        if cookieAcceptConcentButton != None:
            cookieAcceptConcentButton.click()

        """ Find email field and enter paypal user email. """
        emailField = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
        emailField.send_keys(payPalUserEmail)
        
        """ Find next button and click """
        nextButton = self.driver.find_element_by_id('btnNext')
        nextButton.click()
        
        """ Find password field and enter paypal user password. """
        passwordField = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
        passwordField.send_keys(payPalUserPassword)

        """ Find login button and click """
        loginButton = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnLogin")))
        loginButton.click()
        
        """ find button Agree & Continue and click """
        xpath = '//*[@id="consentButton"]'
        print("xpath = " + xpath)
        agreementButton = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))

The last step fails with the following exception in headless mode.
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
E       Stacktrace:
E       0   chromedriver                        0x0000000103161170 chromedriver + 4477296
E       1   chromedriver                        0x00000001030f8c18 chromedriver + 4049944
E       2   chromedriver                        0x0000000102d4ad40 chromedriver + 191808
E       3   chromedriver                        0x0000000102d79b28 chromedriver + 383784
E       4   chromedriver                        0x0000000102da285c chromedriver + 551004
E       5   chromedriver                        0x0000000102d6ef58 chromedriver + 339800
E       6   chromedriver                        0x0000000103136bd4 chromedriver + 4303828
E       7   chromedriver                        0x000000010313b094 chromedriver + 4321428
E       8   chromedriver                        0x000000010313f600 chromedriver + 4339200
E       9   chromedriver                        0x000000010313baf4 chromedriver + 4324084
E       10  chromedriver                        0x000000010311a52c chromedriver + 4187436
E       11  chromedriver                        0x0000000103153488 chromedriver + 4420744
E       12  chromedriver                        0x00000001031535ec chromedriver + 4421100
E       13  chromedriver                        0x000000010316792c chromedriver + 4503852
E       14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001c4f09240 _pthread_start + 148
E       15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001c4f04024 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: it seems like the agreement button never pops up or the xpath to that button is incorrect hence why the wait.until is raising a timeoutexception

Comment: But it works when headless is False.  Why would it fail when headless is True?

Comment: I always debug my headless session with screenshots. Add "driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")" with different image names after each "step" and then check the screenshots to see if you find something unusual.

Comment: I added the screenshot command that you suggested and I think the page looks ok to me.  
self.driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
I also added verbose option    
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(path + 'chromedriver', service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=/Users/rgon/paypal1.log"], chrome_options=chrome_options)

[1654381186.524][INFO]: [4624c90cc14c608faa4a7e70597ff137] RESPONSE FindElement ERROR no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="consentButton"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.61)

Comment: another better approach to debugging this is putting the last line in a try except and put code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))  inside the except run this from cmd this should give you a interactive shell with all the variables already set simply print the html or try finding it using regular code